# Is `!any` valid in JSDoc as the type of a parameter?

Tags: jsdoc

Is `!any` valid in JSDoc as the type of a parameter? And what would it mean?

I was trying to use this to constrain a variable to be of any type except 'null' or 'undefined'. But atleast in VSCode, it seems that this check is not being enforced.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`NonNullable`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) utility type

```js
/**@type {string | null | undefined}*/
let foo;

/**@type {NonNullable<typeof foo>}*/(foo).toLowerCase();
```

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23405